# How to change play's default thread pools?

Tags: playframework-2.3

I am working with Play Framework (Scala) version 2.3.
I want to change play's maximum thread pools size using application.conf.

```
play {
  akka {
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, thread pools size was not changed. I was confirmed by next command in Centos 6.5. 24 threads were exists.

```
ps aux -L
```

Comment: Play uses [4 thread pools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools) and that configures only the default one. Are you sure you are not looking at threads from the other pools?

Comment: Try to check it with thread dump or JConsole or VisulaVM.